# How to avoid out of memory exception during processing large number of bitmaps?

Tags: android, exception, crash, out-of-memory

I am working on an **Android App** in which I`m **merging** more than **100 bitmaps vertically**, I can process only 71 bitmaps after that I get **out of memory exception** and my **App crashes**,Is there any way for avoiding the out of memory exception.

**Note:-**

1. I`m merging the bitmaps vertically using **Canvas**.
2. I`m also utilizing large heap size by using **largeHeap** attribute in manifest file.

code for merging Bitmap is:

```
                    Bitmap mergeBitmap = null;

                    // myBitmapList contains all bitmap Uri, storing size of myBitampList array to size variable
                    int size = myBitmapList.size();
                    int i = 0;

                    // loading first bitmap from the memory
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(),myBitmapList.get(1));
                    Bitmap first = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);

                    Bitmap MergeList = null;
                    Bitmap second = null;
                    int w , h = 0;
                    while (i < size)
                    {
                        // loading second bitmap from the memory
                        Log.e("counter",i+1+"");
                        second = Bitmap.createBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver()
                                ,myBitmapList.get(i)));

                        if (second == null)
                            return;
                        if(i==0)
                            h = first.getHeight() + second.getHeight();
                        else if(MergeList!= null)
                            h = MergeList.getHeight() + second.getHeight();
                        w = second.getWidth();

                        mergeBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mergeBitmap);
                        if (i==0)
                        {
                            canvas.drawBitmap(first, 0f, 0f, null);
                            canvas.drawBitmap(second, 0f, first.getHeight(), null);
                            first.recycle();
                            first = null;

                        }
                        else {
                            if (MergeList != null)
                            {
                                canvas.drawBitmap(MergeList, 0f, 0f, null);
                                canvas.drawBitmap(second, 0f, MergeList.getHeight(), null);
                            }
                        }
                        MergeList = Bitmap.createBitmap(mergeBitmap)
                        i++;
                    }
```

Comment: What ~ size of target bitmap and source bitmaps?

Comment: "Is there any way for avoiding the out of memory exception" -- have fewer or smaller bitmaps. Beyond that, without a [mcve], it will be difficult for anyone to provide specific advice.

Comment: Each bitmap size is about 0.8 mb